# Error SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]

Tags: mysql

When I want to connect with `PDO`:

```
<?php
$host_name = "localhost";
$database = "pdo"; // Change your database name
$username = "root"; // Your database user id 
$password = "test"; // Your password

//////// Do not Edit below /////////
try {
     $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host_name . ';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
     die();
}
?>
```

I get this error message:

```
 Error!: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_name'@'ip.address' (using password: YES)
```

PS: Normally I fill out with my sever information.

Comment: i think you have no password but you are putting there. try with $password = '';

Comment: What's your question? The issue seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: To put it another way - you're connecting with invalid credentials. Check that your username and password are correctly set up to let you access the database.

Comment: I have tested your code by default root password is just empty so if you follow @AK-Sonu advice it should work.